# Asserting a Page Using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I Am new to selenium.

my question are:

1) How to assert whether particular page loaded or not or id present in the page through selenium web driver.(Using Java code)

2) For best performance in selenium web driver which code is preferred i.e selenium web driver code or junit code

Comment: Selenium and Junit are totally different things,it has absolutely no relation with the performance of selenium tests.Show us what you have tried,I think selecting an element is pretty straightforward,driver.findElement(By.id("Element ID"))

Comment: @Madusudanam: for Page ?

Comment: It is better to check/wait for the element in the page.Selenium has a blocking API and will usually wait until the page is fully loaded,unless you are doing something that selenium is not aware of.

Comment: @Vinod: For a page you can take few parameter that can uniquely identify the page. For example title, any text, any locator or set of locators. If all of them present on newly opened page, then the newly opened page is expected else not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for a text in your web page like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("BODY")).getText()
                .matches("^[\\s\\S]*" + YOUR TEXT + "[\\s\\S]*$"))
```

Or you can check the page title with  `driver.getTitle();`